# Size to fit on a Visifire Line Chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, visifire

I'm using Visifire. I have plotted about 500+ points on a line chart. However, after plotting the points, a horizontal scroll bar is placed on the bottom of my chart. I then have to scroll over to see the entire chart. Is there a "SizeToFit" method I'm missing so I can see my entire dataset? If not, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:

I have tried setting the axisX.AxisMinimum and AxisMaximum properties... those didn't fix my problem. I have also tried setting the axisX width property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if I set the "ScrollingEnabled" property of the chart to "false" it solves my problem. However, the chart looks awful now... but I guess that's another issue =)